# Relative links broken after migrating staging to development in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Trying to migrate Wordpress *staging* website hosted on some hosting provider to local computer and having issues with relative urls.

**Migration steps**:

1) Cloned site code repository
2) Imported mysql dump
3) Used [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org) to search and replace staging site url with 
*localhost/site*

Everything seems fine apart from some relative url.

**Example of issues**:

*Correct linking*

Sub menu *Travel* links to page *Travel* (whose slug is *travel*), so clicking it redirects to the correct path *siteurl/travel*.
Where siteurl is *localhost/site* hosted in */var/www/html/site*.

*Incorrect linking*

The widget area image link */travel* somehow links to the wrong path *localhost/travel*. 
Its *Settings->General->WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)* are: *localhost/site*

I think it's related somehow to *.htaccess* file or apache server configuration.

Localhost site *.htaccess* file contents are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /site/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Generally, my question, what apache server configuration is needed to replicate the behaviour of relative links on hosting? So that relative links on the website like */link* would be relative to the wordpress site url (*localhost/site/link*) and not relative to host - *localhost/link*.

Comment: Do you have other sites hosted on `localhost`?

Comment: yes, there are sites on _localhost_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So that relative links on the website like `/link` would be relative to the wordpress site url (`localhost/site/link`) and not relative to host - `localhost/link`.

The URL `/link` (with a slash prefix) is root-relative, not simply "relative". This will be relative to the document root ie. `http://localhost/link` in your example. However, a URL of the form `link` (no slash prefix) is *relative* - that is relative to the current URL-path (in the browser). So, given the URL `http://localhost/site/file`, a relative URL of the form `link` will naturally resolve (by the browser) to `http://localhost/site/link` - which would seem to be correct in your example. However, given the URL `http://localhost/site/path/to/file`, the same relative URL will resolve to `http://localhost/site/path/to/link` - which probably wouldn't be desirable, so relative links are not really the answer (best avoided when URL-rewritting).  So, this is ultimately a client-side issue - it is the browser that resolves relative URL-paths - not the server.

To fix this, you need to either change all the URLs so they resolve correctly (ie. make them *relative* in your case it seems - although this would often be the cause of problems on a WordPress site - if you changed your permalink structure then all your links break), which may not work very well if you are ultimately moving the site to another server. Or change the document root of your site and remove the `/site` subdirectory. If you weren't hosting multiple sites from different subdirectories you could resolve this with a rewrite in `.htaccess`. However, in your case, that would break all the other sites that operate out of their own subdirectory.

You really need to setup your separate sites on your local development machine as *separate sites*, not as subdirectories off what is essentially just a single site (ie. `http://localhost/`). This involves creating separate `<VirtualHost>` containers within the server config that defines a separate `DocumentRoot` for each site. You'll need to also use your local HOSTS file (or DNS) to point a domain to your local development server.

So, your *site URL* in WordPress would become something like `http://local.example.com/` which would be hosted from somewhere like `/var/www/example.com/public_html` on your development machine.

Answer (score 0):

As *MrWhite* suggested the following steps solved the issues:

1) **Adding [vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html#page-header) block to *apache2.conf* configuration file of *Apache*.**

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80>
   ServerName local.site.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/local.site"
</VirtualHost>
```

- */var/www/html/local.site* is the folder on local machine where all the website files are.
- *local.site.com* is  the domain name of the local website
- *VirtualHost* directive has an explicit IP address discoverable by running *ip addr show* in the command line to support multiple name-based virtual hosts on one ip address

2) **Adding the following entry to */etc/hosts***

> 192.168.1.10 local.site.com

To conform to note [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

> Creating virtual host configurations on your Apache server does not
>   magically cause DNS entries to be created for those host names. You
>   must have the names in DNS, resolving to your IP address, or nobody
>   else will be able to see your web site. You can put entries in your
>   hosts file for local testing, but that will work only from the machine
>   with those hosts entries.

3) **Using the same .htaccess from the staging website**

It basically contains the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

There may be much more directives originating from security wordpress plugins. If they use staging website url like in:

```
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://site.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://site.com [NC]` should be replaced with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://local.site.com [NC]`

All the steps were run after:

1. Cloning site code repository to local development environment
2. Importing mysql dump to local mysql db
3. Using [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org) to
   search and replace staging site url with *local.site.com*